# Combining multiple Javascript files into one

Tags: javascript, file, external

Probably something really obvious, but Javascript is not my forté, so I need some advice.

I'm using a bootstrap template for my website, and it came out of the box with 8 Javascript files, and I've also created another one. Loading 9 Javascript files makes my website slow to load, hence I want to combine some of the files into one and improve speed.

I assumed I could just copy and paste File A into File B and I'd keep the same functionality... However, when I do this with the following files, I lose the functionality of File A from my site altogether.

File A:

```
document.body.addEventListener('change', e => {
  if (e.target && e.target.classList.contains('goto')) {
    window.location.href = e.target.dataset.target;
  }
});
```

File B:

```
AOS.init({
    duration: 800,
    easing: 'slide',
    once: true
});

// tried inserting it here

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    "use strict";

    var slider = function() {
        $('.nonloop-block-3').owlCarousel({
            center: false,
            items: 1,
            loop: false,
            stagePadding: 15,
            margin: 20,
            nav: true,
            navText: ['<span class="icon-arrow_back">', '<span class="icon-arrow_forward">'],
            responsive: {
                600: {
                    margin: 20,
                    items: 2
                },
                1000: {
                    margin: 20,
                    items: 3
                },
                1200: {
                    margin: 20,
                    items: 3
                }
            }
        });
    };
    slider();


    var siteMenuClone = function() {

        $('<div class="site-mobile-menu"></div>').prependTo('.site-wrap');

        $('<div class="site-mobile-menu-header"></div>').prependTo('.site-mobile-menu');
        $('<div class="site-mobile-menu-close "></div>').prependTo('.site-mobile-menu-header');
        $('<div class="site-mobile-menu-logo"></div>').prependTo('.site-mobile-menu-header');

        $('<div class="site-mobile-menu-body"></div>').appendTo('.site-mobile-menu');



        $('.js-logo-clone').clone().appendTo('.site-mobile-menu-logo');

        $('<span class="ion-ios-close js-menu-toggle"></div>').prependTo('.site-mobile-menu-close');


        $('.js-clone-nav').each(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.clone().attr('class', 'site-nav-wrap').appendTo('.site-mobile-menu-body');
        });


        setTimeout(function() {

            var counter = 0;
            $('.site-mobile-menu .has-children').each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);

                $this.prepend('<span class="arrow-collapse collapsed">');

                $this.find('.arrow-collapse').attr({
                    'data-toggle': 'collapse',
                    'data-target': '#collapseItem' + counter,
                });

                $this.find('> ul').attr({
                    'class': 'collapse',
                    'id': 'collapseItem' + counter,
                });

                counter++;

            });

        }, 1000);

        $('body').on('click', '.arrow-collapse', function(e) {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.closest('li').find('.collapse').hasClass('show')) {
                $this.removeClass('active');
            } else {
                $this.addClass('active');
            }
            e.preventDefault();

        });

        $(window).resize(function() {
            var $this = $(this),
                w = $this.width();

            if (w > 768) {
                if ($('body').hasClass('offcanvas-menu')) {
                    $('body').removeClass('offcanvas-menu');
                }
            }
        })

        $('body').on('click', '.js-menu-toggle', function(e) {
            var $this = $(this);
            e.preventDefault();

            if ($('body').hasClass('offcanvas-menu')) {
                $('body').removeClass('offcanvas-menu');
                $this.removeClass('active');
            } else {
                $('body').addClass('offcanvas-menu');
                $this.addClass('active');
            }
        })

        // click outisde offcanvas
        $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
            var container = $(".site-mobile-menu");
            if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
                if ($('body').hasClass('offcanvas-menu')) {
                    $('body').removeClass('offcanvas-menu');
                }
            }
        });
    };
    siteMenuClone();


    var sitePlusMinus = function() {
        $('.js-btn-minus').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($(this).closest('.input-group').find('.form-control').val() != 0) {
                $(this).closest('.input-group').find('.form-control').val(parseInt($(this).closest('.input-group').find('.form-control').val()) - 1);
            } else {
                $(this).closest('.input-group').find('.form-control').val(parseInt(0));
            }
        });
        $('.js-btn-plus').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest('.input-group').find('.form-control').val(parseInt($(this).closest('.input-group').find('.form-control').val()) + 1);
        });
    };
    sitePlusMinus();


    var siteSliderRange = function() {
        $("#slider-range").slider({
            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 500,
            values: [75, 300],
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                $("#amount").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - $" + ui.values[1]);
            }
        });
        $("#amount").val("$" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +
            " - $" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
    };
    siteSliderRange();


    var siteMagnificPopup = function() {
        $('.image-popup').magnificPopup({
            type: 'image',
            closeOnContentClick: true,
            closeBtnInside: false,
            fixedContentPos: true,
            mainClass: 'mfp-no-margins mfp-with-zoom', // class to remove default margin from left and right side
            gallery: {
                enabled: true,
                navigateByImgClick: true,
                preload: [0, 1] // Will preload 0 - before current, and 1 after the current image
            },
            image: {
                verticalFit: true
            },
            zoom: {
                enabled: true,
                duration: 300 // don't foget to change the duration also in CSS
            }
        });

        $('.popup-youtube, .popup-vimeo, .popup-gmaps').magnificPopup({
            disableOn: 700,
            type: 'iframe',
            mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
            removalDelay: 160,
            preloader: false,

            fixedContentPos: false
        });
    };
    siteMagnificPopup();

});

// tried inserting it here too...
```

I'm assuming this is some sort of rookie mistake because I'm not overly familiar with Javascript, rather than a bug, so any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you share how the script tags look for the original `A` and `B` and where they appear in the HTML document?